# expansion panel always open when using tabs in with angular material

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have created tabs and expansion panel inside one of tabs.

**My problem** is when I select the tab containing panels they are collapsed but panel's content is visible.

[image]

I have seen that it's an issue in angular material 5 and was solved in Angular Material 6.0.0.beta0 but for the moment I can't update my package.json. so I have tried a workaround in Angular Material 5v s mentioned [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5269#issuecomment-326692430) but it's not working for me.

Here's what I did

In my parent component I pass `selectedIndex` value to components using `Input()`

```
<div flexLayout="column">
  <mat-tab-group [(selectedIndex)]="selectedTabIndex" fxFlex="70" fxFlex.xs="100">
    <mat-tab label="A propos de moi">  
      <app-a-propos></app-a-propos>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Formation et experiences">
      <app-experiences [selectedTabIndex]=selectedTabIndex></app-experiences>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Projets Perso"> 
      <app-projets [selectedTabIndex]=selectedTabIndex></app-projets>
    </mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
</div>
```

in **app-experiences.html**

```
<div *ngIf="selectedTabIndex == 1">
    <mat-accordion>
      <mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="false">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header class="right-aligned-header">
          <mat-panel-title>
            Cycle ingénieur en informatique
          </mat-panel-title>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      </mat-expansion-panel>      
      <mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="false">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header class="right-aligned-header">
          <mat-panel-title>
            Cycle préparatoire integré
          </mat-panel-title>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      </mat-expansion-panel>
    </mat-accordion>
  </div>
```

And in **app-experiences.ts**

```
export class ExperiencesComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() selectedTabIndex: number;
  constructor() { }
  panelOpenState = true;
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

How can I set panels expanded option to false without using Angular Material 5.2.0 ?

Comment: As a suggestion you can read this https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5269 But there is no clear fix for this issue